# Помогите с телефонной формой

Tags: html

запланирована форма для отправки телефона на сервер ( это всё есть )
Верстальщик с меня конечно не ахти, можете глянуть и исправить

1) На странице видать что то еще раз скролит, мне нужно чтобы форма была по центру, а галка под формой.
2) У меня в форме событие пока не будут введены все цифры, кнопка отправить не будет активна, то же самое хочу применить и к галочке, пока форма и галка не будут заполнены кнопка отправить не будет активна.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
У меня беда с разметкой, учус только.)
Вот, посмотрите ребят http://zalil.su/1470357

Comment: Ну так тут ряд действий, стили и обработка js вы что то знаете? JS или JQuery

Comment: Во первых, лучше код добавьте, во вторых, тут и правда не только html и css но и JS. Если не можете скинуть рабочий код, сделайте в ‘codepen.io’ или другой песочнице.

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения *прямо в вопросе*. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Добавил, помогите плиз, что где исправить, что добавить. Я выше писал что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как вариант, с проверкой перед отправкой. Регулярку берите любую удобную тут я не замарачивался взял отсюда: [Регулярки](http://html5pattern.com/Phones#n=Name%E2%80%A6&p=Pattern%E2%80%A6&d=Description%E2%80%A6&s=Source%E2%80%A6&pc[0]=%2B&nc[0]=-)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
  position: ralative;
}

.center {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.center>p {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<form class="center" onSubmit="alert('Ok')">
  <p>
    <input type="tel" pattern="^(?:0|\(?\+33\)?\s?|0033\s?)[1-79](?:[\.\-\s]?\d\d){4}$" required />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
/*
 jQuery Masked Input Plugin
 Copyright (c) 2007 - 2015 Josh Bush (digitalbush.com)
 Licensed under the MIT license (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#license)
 Version: 1.4.1
 */
!function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):a("object"==typeof exports?require("jquery"):jQuery)}(function(a){var b,c=navigator.userAgent,d=/iphone/i.test(c),e=/chrome/i.test(c),f=/android/i.test(c);a.mask={definitions:{9:"[0-9]",a:"[A-Za-z]","*":"[A-Za-z0-9]"},autoclear:!0,dataName:"rawMaskFn",placeholder:"_"},a.fn.extend({caret:function(a,b){var c;if(0!==this.length&&!this.is(":hidden"))return"number"==typeof a?(b="number"==typeof b?b:a,this.each(function(){this.setSelectionRange?this.setSelectionRange(a,b):this.createTextRange&&(c=this.createTextRange(),c.collapse(!0),c.moveEnd("character",b),c.moveStart("character",a),c.select())})):(this[0].setSelectionRange?(a=this[0].selectionStart,b=this[0].selectionEnd):document.selection&&document.selection.createRange&&(c=document.selection.createRange(),a=0-c.duplicate().moveStart("character",-1e5),b=a+c.text.length),{begin:a,end:b})},unmask:function(){return this.trigger("unmask")},mask:function(c,g){var h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o;if(!c&&this.length>0){h=a(this[0]);var p=h.data(a.mask.dataName);return p?p():void 0}return g=a.extend({autoclear:a.mask.autoclear,placeholder:a.mask.placeholder,completed:null},g),i=a.mask.definitions,j=[],k=n=c.length,l=null,a.each(c.split(""),function(a,b){"?"==b?(n--,k=a):i[b]?(j.push(new RegExp(i[b])),null===l&&(l=j.length-1),k>a&&(m=j.length-1)):j.push(null)}),this.trigger("unmask").each(function(){function h(){if(g.completed){for(var a=l;m>=a;a++)if(j[a]&&C[a]===p(a))return;g.completed.call(B)}}function p(a){return g.placeholder.charAt(a<g.placeholder.length?a:0)}function q(a){for(;++a<n&&!j[a];);return a}function r(a){for(;--a>=0&&!j[a];);return a}function s(a,b){var c,d;if(!(0>a)){for(c=a,d=q(b);n>c;c++)if(j[c]){if(!(n>d&&j[c].test(C[d])))break;C[c]=C[d],C[d]=p(d),d=q(d)}z(),B.caret(Math.max(l,a))}}function t(a){var b,c,d,e;for(b=a,c=p(a);n>b;b++)if(j[b]){if(d=q(b),e=C[b],C[b]=c,!(n>d&&j[d].test(e)))break;c=e}}function u(){var a=B.val(),b=B.caret();if(o&&o.length&&o.length>a.length){for(A(!0);b.begin>0&&!j[b.begin-1];)b.begin--;if(0===b.begin)for(;b.begin<l&&!j[b.begin];)b.begin++;B.caret(b.begin,b.begin)}else{for(A(!0);b.begin<n&&!j[b.begin];)b.begin++;B.caret(b.begin,b.begin)}h()}function v(){A(),B.val()!=E&&B.change()}function w(a){if(!B.prop("readonly")){var b,c,e,f=a.which||a.keyCode;o=B.val(),8===f||46===f||d&&127===f?(b=B.caret(),c=b.begin,e=b.end,e-c===0&&(c=46!==f?r(c):e=q(c-1),e=46===f?q(e):e),y(c,e),s(c,e-1),a.preventDefault()):13===f?v.call(this,a):27===f&&(B.val(E),B.caret(0,A()),a.preventDefault())}}function x(b){if(!B.prop("readonly")){var c,d,e,g=b.which||b.keyCode,i=B.caret();if(!(b.ctrlKey||b.altKey||b.metaKey||32>g)&&g&&13!==g){if(i.end-i.begin!==0&&(y(i.begin,i.end),s(i.begin,i.end-1)),c=q(i.begin-1),n>c&&(d=String.fromCharCode(g),j[c].test(d))){if(t(c),C[c]=d,z(),e=q(c),f){var k=function(){a.proxy(a.fn.caret,B,e)()};setTimeout(k,0)}else B.caret(e);i.begin<=m&&h()}b.preventDefault()}}}function y(a,b){var c;for(c=a;b>c&&n>c;c++)j[c]&&(C[c]=p(c))}function z(){B.val(C.join(""))}function A(a){var b,c,d,e=B.val(),f=-1;for(b=0,d=0;n>b;b++)if(j[b]){for(C[b]=p(b);d++<e.length;)if(c=e.charAt(d-1),j[b].test(c)){C[b]=c,f=b;break}if(d>e.length){y(b+1,n);break}}else C[b]===e.charAt(d)&&d++,k>b&&(f=b);return a?z():k>f+1?g.autoclear||C.join("")===D?(B.val()&&B.val(""),y(0,n)):z():(z(),B.val(B.val().substring(0,f+1))),k?b:l}var B=a(this),C=a.map(c.split(""),function(a,b){return"?"!=a?i[a]?p(b):a:void 0}),D=C.join(""),E=B.val();B.data(a.mask.dataName,function(){return a.map(C,function(a,b){return j[b]&&a!=p(b)?a:null}).join("")}),B.one("unmask",function(){B.off(".mask").removeData(a.mask.dataName)}).on("focus.mask",function(){if(!B.prop("readonly")){clearTimeout(b);var a;E=B.val(),a=A(),b=setTimeout(function(){B.get(0)===document.activeElement&&(z(),a==c.replace("?","").length?B.caret(0,a):B.caret(a))},10)}}).on("blur.mask",v).on("keydown.mask",w).on("keypress.mask",x).on("input.mask paste.mask",function(){B.prop("readonly")||setTimeout(function(){var a=A(!0);B.caret(a),h()},0)}),e&&f&&B.off("input.mask").on("input.mask",u),A()})}})});
(function( $ ){
 
  var $body;

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $body = $('body');

    $body
      .find('.user-phone').each(function(){
          $(this).mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99",{autoclear: false});
      });

    $body.on('keyup','.user-phone',function(){
      var phone = $(this),
          phoneVal = phone.val(),
          form = $(this).parents('form');

      if ( (phoneVal.indexOf("_") != -1) || phoneVal == '' ) {
        form.find('.btn_submit').attr('disabled',true);
      } else {
        form.find('.btn_submit').removeAttr('disabled');
      }

      
    });

  });

})( jQuery );
```

```css
/* = Общие стили
************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) { div. contentblock {width: 970px;} }
a {text-decoration: none;}

/* =Стили для header'а
************************/
html{ 

}
body{
 
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #5cea98, #d0a4e3);
 
  }


/* Main */

.phone_form {
 width: 520px;
 margin: 300px auto;
 
}
.user-phone {
 width: 400px;
 position: relative;
 /*padding: 8px 8px 8px 36px;*/
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 16px 16px;
 font-size: 33px;
 color: #363636;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 30px;
}

}
input.user-phone:-moz-placeholder {
 color: #363636;


}
input.user-phone::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #363636;

}
.btn_submit {
 height: 92px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 92px;
 left: 275px;
 background: #363636;
 color: #fff;
 border: none;
 width: 200px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
 border-radius: 0 16px 16px 0;
 font-size: 35px;


}
.btn_submit[disabled] {
 color: #363636;
 background: #ccc;
}




[id^=c]{
    display: none;
}
[id^=c] + label{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-align: center;   
    position: relative;
    background-color: #FFF;
    
}
[id^=c] + label:before{
    content: '';    
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(45% 64%, 84% 14%, 100% 28%, 47% 100%, 0 49%, 15% 32%);
clip-path: polygon(45% 64%, 84% 14%, 100% 28%, 47% 100%, 0 49%, 15% 32%);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s;
    transition: transform .3s;
}
[id^=c]:checked + label:before{    
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 10)|!(IE)]><!--><html> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

 <title>Отправка номера</title>
 
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all" />
 
</head>




    
        
          
</header>
<body>



 
<form action="#" method="post" class="phone_form">
 
 <div class="user_phone">
    <input style="height: 80px;" type="tel" required placeholder="+7" id="user_phone" class="user-phone" title="Формат: +7 (xxx) xxx xx xx"/>
 </div>
 
 <input type="submit" class="btn_submit" disabled />
 <input type="checkbox" name="c1" id="c1" />
<label for="c1"></label>
 
</form>

</div>

</section>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если не чего не переделывать, то можно просто для `<label for="c1">` задать position: absolute и top: 400px =)

Comment: Господа, прошу помощи. 1) На странице видать что то еще раз скролит, мне нужно чтобы форма была по центру, а галка под формой. 2) У меня в форме событие пока не будут введены все цифры, кнопка отправить не будет активна, то же самое хочу применить и к галочке, пока форма и галка не будут заполнены кнопка отправить не будет активна.

Comment: И как можно реализовать чтобы при наведении окошечка с галочкой была :hover обводка border, но при нажатии на галочку оставалась галочка с этой же обводкой?

Comment: Если я правильно понял про про чекбокс https://jsfiddle.net/uj9wx0sa/

Comment: nicolaa, совершенно верно.  А это случаем не знаете как реализовать? "У меня в форме событие пока не будут введены все цифры, кнопка отправить не будет активна, то же самое хочу применить и к галочке, пока форма и галка не будут заполнены кнопка отправить не будет активна"

Comment: Как изменить текст на кнопке отправить текст на Отправить по SMS??

Comment: Добавь атрибут value для `<input type="submit" class="btn_submit" disabled />`  `value="текст"`

Comment: Спасибо, uer242856.

Comment: Как сделать так, чтобы текст при уменьшении окна не налезал на форму? У меня сверху формы текст h3

Answer (score 0):

Постарался в коде немного расписать, что да как
А по поводу скрола хз, у меня все норм

```js
/*
 jQuery Masked Input Plugin
 Copyright (c) 2007 - 2015 Josh Bush (digitalbush.com)
 Licensed under the MIT license (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#license)
 Version: 1.4.1
 */
!function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):a("object"==typeof exports?require("jquery"):jQuery)}(function(a){var b,c=navigator.userAgent,d=/iphone/i.test(c),e=/chrome/i.test(c),f=/android/i.test(c);a.mask={definitions:{9:"[0-9]",a:"[A-Za-z]","*":"[A-Za-z0-9]"},autoclear:!0,dataName:"rawMaskFn",placeholder:"_"},a.fn.extend({caret:function(a,b){var c;if(0!==this.length&&!this.is(":hidden"))return"number"==typeof a?(b="number"==typeof b?b:a,this.each(function(){this.setSelectionRange?this.setSelectionRange(a,b):this.createTextRange&&(c=this.createTextRange(),c.collapse(!0),c.moveEnd("character",b),c.moveStart("character",a),c.select())})):(this[0].setSelectionRange?(a=this[0].selectionStart,b=this[0].selectionEnd):document.selection&&document.selection.createRange&&(c=document.selection.createRange(),a=0-c.duplicate().moveStart("character",-1e5),b=a+c.text.length),{begin:a,end:b})},unmask:function(){return this.trigger("unmask")},mask:function(c,g){var h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o;if(!c&&this.length>0){h=a(this[0]);var p=h.data(a.mask.dataName);return p?p():void 0}return g=a.extend({autoclear:a.mask.autoclear,placeholder:a.mask.placeholder,completed:null},g),i=a.mask.definitions,j=[],k=n=c.length,l=null,a.each(c.split(""),function(a,b){"?"==b?(n--,k=a):i[b]?(j.push(new RegExp(i[b])),null===l&&(l=j.length-1),k>a&&(m=j.length-1)):j.push(null)}),this.trigger("unmask").each(function(){function h(){if(g.completed){for(var a=l;m>=a;a++)if(j[a]&&C[a]===p(a))return;g.completed.call(B)}}function p(a){return g.placeholder.charAt(a<g.placeholder.length?a:0)}function q(a){for(;++a<n&&!j[a];);return a}function r(a){for(;--a>=0&&!j[a];);return a}function s(a,b){var c,d;if(!(0>a)){for(c=a,d=q(b);n>c;c++)if(j[c]){if(!(n>d&&j[c].test(C[d])))break;C[c]=C[d],C[d]=p(d),d=q(d)}z(),B.caret(Math.max(l,a))}}function t(a){var b,c,d,e;for(b=a,c=p(a);n>b;b++)if(j[b]){if(d=q(b),e=C[b],C[b]=c,!(n>d&&j[d].test(e)))break;c=e}}function u(){var a=B.val(),b=B.caret();if(o&&o.length&&o.length>a.length){for(A(!0);b.begin>0&&!j[b.begin-1];)b.begin--;if(0===b.begin)for(;b.begin<l&&!j[b.begin];)b.begin++;B.caret(b.begin,b.begin)}else{for(A(!0);b.begin<n&&!j[b.begin];)b.begin++;B.caret(b.begin,b.begin)}h()}function v(){A(),B.val()!=E&&B.change()}function w(a){if(!B.prop("readonly")){var b,c,e,f=a.which||a.keyCode;o=B.val(),8===f||46===f||d&&127===f?(b=B.caret(),c=b.begin,e=b.end,e-c===0&&(c=46!==f?r(c):e=q(c-1),e=46===f?q(e):e),y(c,e),s(c,e-1),a.preventDefault()):13===f?v.call(this,a):27===f&&(B.val(E),B.caret(0,A()),a.preventDefault())}}function x(b){if(!B.prop("readonly")){var c,d,e,g=b.which||b.keyCode,i=B.caret();if(!(b.ctrlKey||b.altKey||b.metaKey||32>g)&&g&&13!==g){if(i.end-i.begin!==0&&(y(i.begin,i.end),s(i.begin,i.end-1)),c=q(i.begin-1),n>c&&(d=String.fromCharCode(g),j[c].test(d))){if(t(c),C[c]=d,z(),e=q(c),f){var k=function(){a.proxy(a.fn.caret,B,e)()};setTimeout(k,0)}else B.caret(e);i.begin<=m&&h()}b.preventDefault()}}}function y(a,b){var c;for(c=a;b>c&&n>c;c++)j[c]&&(C[c]=p(c))}function z(){B.val(C.join(""))}function A(a){var b,c,d,e=B.val(),f=-1;for(b=0,d=0;n>b;b++)if(j[b]){for(C[b]=p(b);d++<e.length;)if(c=e.charAt(d-1),j[b].test(c)){C[b]=c,f=b;break}if(d>e.length){y(b+1,n);break}}else C[b]===e.charAt(d)&&d++,k>b&&(f=b);return a?z():k>f+1?g.autoclear||C.join("")===D?(B.val()&&B.val(""),y(0,n)):z():(z(),B.val(B.val().substring(0,f+1))),k?b:l}var B=a(this),C=a.map(c.split(""),function(a,b){return"?"!=a?i[a]?p(b):a:void 0}),D=C.join(""),E=B.val();B.data(a.mask.dataName,function(){return a.map(C,function(a,b){return j[b]&&a!=p(b)?a:null}).join("")}),B.one("unmask",function(){B.off(".mask").removeData(a.mask.dataName)}).on("focus.mask",function(){if(!B.prop("readonly")){clearTimeout(b);var a;E=B.val(),a=A(),b=setTimeout(function(){B.get(0)===document.activeElement&&(z(),a==c.replace("?","").length?B.caret(0,a):B.caret(a))},10)}}).on("blur.mask",v).on("keydown.mask",w).on("keypress.mask",x).on("input.mask paste.mask",function(){B.prop("readonly")||setTimeout(function(){var a=A(!0);B.caret(a),h()},0)}),e&&f&&B.off("input.mask").on("input.mask",u),A()})}})});
(function( $ ){
 
  var $body;

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $body = $('body');

    $body
      .find('.user-phone').each(function(){
          $(this).mask("+7 (999) 999-99-99",{autoclear: false});
      });

    /*Решил сделать по своему, закомментировал стандартное отключение кнопки, при желании код ниже можно просто удалить*/
    $body.on('keyup','.user-phone',function(){
      var phone = $(this),
          phoneVal = phone.val(),
          form = $(this).parents('form');

      if ( (phoneVal.indexOf("_") != -1) || phoneVal == '' ) {
        /* form.find('.btn_submit').attr('disabled',true) */;
      } else {
        /* form.find('.btn_submit').removeAttr('disabled') */;
      }

      
    });
    /*До сюда*/
    
    $('#user_phone').keyup(function(){//Отслеживаем нажатие клавиш
      var val = $(this).val().replace(/\D+/g,"");//Оставляем только цифры
      if(val.length >= 11) {//Проверяем на кол-во цифр
        if($('#c1').is(":checked")) {//Проверяем нажат ли чекбокс
          $('.btn_submit').removeAttr('disabled');//Если нажат активируем кнопку
        } else {
          $('.btn_submit').attr('disabled',true);//Если не нажат выключаем кнопку
        }
      } else {
        $('.btn_submit').attr('disabled',true);//Если цифр меньше 11 выключаем чек бокс
      }
    });
    $('#c1').change(function(){//Отслеживаем нажатие на чекбокс
      if($(this).is(":checked")) {//Если чекбокс нажат
        var val = $('#user_phone').val().replace(/\D+/g,"");//Достаем все из инпута и оставляем только цифры
        if(val.length >= 11) {//Проверяем на кол-во цифр
          $('.btn_submit').removeAttr('disabled');//Если цифр больше 11 активируем кнопку
        } else {
          $('.btn_submit').attr('disabled',true);//Если меньше 11 выключаем кнопку
        }
      } else {
        $('.btn_submit').attr('disabled',true);//Если чек бокс не нажат выключаем кнопку
      }
    });

  });

})( jQuery );
```

```css
/* = Общие стили
************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) { div. contentblock {width: 970px;} }
a {text-decoration: none;}

/* =Стили для header'а
************************/
html{ 

}
body{
 
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #5cea98, #d0a4e3);
 
  }


/* Main */

.phone_form {
 width: 520px;
 margin: 300px auto;
 
}
.user-phone {
 width: 400px;
 position: relative;
 /*padding: 8px 8px 8px 36px;*/
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 16px 16px;
 font-size: 33px;
 color: #363636;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 30px;
}

}
input.user-phone:-moz-placeholder {
 color: #363636;


}
input.user-phone::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #363636;

}
.btn_submit {
 height: 92px;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 92px;
 left: 275px;
 background: #363636;
 color: #fff;
 border: none;
 width: 200px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
 border-radius: 0 16px 16px 0;
 font-size: 35px;


}
.btn_submit[disabled] {
 color: #363636;
 background: #ccc;
}




[id^=c]{
    display: none;
}
[id^=c] + label{
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-align: center;   
    /* position: relative; */
    background-color: #FFF;
    
}
[id^=c] + label:before{
    content: '';    
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(45% 64%, 84% 14%, 100% 28%, 47% 100%, 0 49%, 15% 32%);
clip-path: polygon(45% 64%, 84% 14%, 100% 28%, 47% 100%, 0 49%, 15% 32%);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: transform .3s;
    transition: transform .3s;
}
[id^=c]:checked + label:before{    
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
/*При наведении на чекбокс добавляем обводку*/
[id^=c] + label:hover {
  border: 4px solid #000;
}
/*При выборе чекбокса ставим обводку*/
[id^=c]:checked + label {
    border: 4px solid #000;
}
/*Текст рядом с чекбоксом*/
.text-for-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 34%;
  margin-top: 17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 10)|!(IE)]><!--><html> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

 <title>Отправка номера</title>
 
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all" />
 
</head>




    
        
          
</header>
<body>



 
<form action="#" method="post" class="phone_form">
 
 <div class="user_phone">
    <input style="height: 80px;" type="tel" required placeholder="+7" id="user_phone" class="user-phone" title="Формат: +7 (xxx) xxx xx xx"/>
 </div>
 
 <input type="submit" class="btn_submit" disabled />
 <input type="checkbox" name="c1" id="c1" />
<label for="c1"></label><span class="text-for-checkbox">Text</span>
 
</form>

</div>

</section>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, nicola. то что надо) Хочу сдклать рядом с галкой поле с текстом, лучше создавать как? Div? а в нем текст? <p>?

Comment: Тут я наверное бы сделал так(Подправил ответ)

Comment: Что нужно чтобы адаптировать под мобильное устройство ?

Comment: Как изменить текст на кнопке отправить текст на Отправить по SMS??